# Difference in functions

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

I am just curious if there is a difference between these two different types of functions.

```
function PrintHello()
    return print("Hello")
end
```

and

```
PrintHello = function()
    return print("Hello")
```

Comment: For global functions there is no difference.  But local functions `local function f() end` vs `local f = function() end` are different when you are trying to define recursive function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beside that you're missing an end in the second function both snippets are equivalent.

According to the [Lua 5.4 Reference Manual 3.4.11 - Function Definitions](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.4.11)

```
function PrintHello ()
  print("Hello")
end
```

translates to

```
PrintHello = function ()
  print("Hello")
end
```

As you'll also find in the manual there is a difference for local functions.

```
local function a() end
```

translates to

```
local function a;
a = function () end
```

This allows a to reference itself for example in a recursive call.

Instead of `return print("Hello")` simply write `print("Hello")`. `print` has no return value.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and the answer, I have the Lua book but I think I need to start to read it. I thought I knew the language to an okay level just not everything. :)

Answer (score -1):

function PrintHello ()
print("Hello")
end

Comment: how is this an answer to the question?